A problem of probability which is related to recursion in a game
Recently I have been playing a game called Warframe. I found a curious problem of probability for me in the game. I don't know how to calculate it, so I want to ask for help.
The problem could be simplified below:
There is a continuous action sequence when playing a match that assuming a player has to use a skill sequence $\{1,1,2\}$ which means that using 1st skill, 1st skill, and 2nd skill in order. By the way, if you use 1st skill, you would spend $a$ points of energy. Similarly, using 2nd skill will spend $b$ points of energy.
Then, a player equipped an item that there is a $p$ chance, while using any skill, makes using the next three skills will not spend any points of energy.
What I want to calculate is the expected value of used points of energy when finished  the skill sequence $\{1,1,2\}$ every time.
Assuming $a=25, b=50,p=0.2$, the simulation shows the value is about $51$.
And this is my code below:
countdown = 0 # marked how many chances to avoid spending energy we have.

p = 0.2 # chance
t = 10000 # marked how many times to execute the whole action sequence we need.
cost = 0 # total energy cost
seq = [25,25,50] # energy cost of the action sequence

for i in range(1, t+1):
    # ↓ execute them in order as 1st, 1st, 2nd skill.
    for j in range(3):
        if countdown == 0:
            # no existed effect because of countdown = 0, we need pay for it
            cost += seq[j]
        else:
            # no any cost because of existed effect, and then `countdown -= 1`
            # cost += 0
            countdown -= 1
            
        # roll dice
        if random.random() < p:
            # nice shot
            countdown = 3

print(cost / t)



What I mean is that the player can equip this item so that in a match, when using any skill, there is a certain probability that using the next three skills will not cost any energy.
I have absolutely no idea how to build a probabilistic model to solve this problem...


For what it is worth, this question would likely be well received at [rpg.se], with the statistics tag.  I don't think that it is necessarily off-topic here, but it is a little niche, and the folks at RPG.se might be able to help you do things like implement an AnyDice script.

Consider the first action. It costs $a$, unless the item has activated in the past three rounds. Since the the probability that the item fails to activate for $3$ times in a row is $(1-p)^3$, the expected cost for the first item is
$$
(1-p)^3\cdot a+\big(1-(1-p)^3\big)\cdot 0=(1-p)^3a.
$$
Similarly, the costs for the second and third rounds in the repeating cycle are $(1-p)^3a$ and $(1-p)^3b$. This means the average cost per cycle is
$$
(1-p)^3(2a+b).
$$
Indeed, when $a=25$ and $b=50$ and $p=0.2$, we get $(0.8)^3\cdot 100=51.2$.

Indeed, I checked my simulation again, and I found a mistake and then fixed it. But the result still shows we have difference. The new result is about 51. I will paste my code later.

I think the cost of the 1st step in your answer is not always 25, because its cost could be affected by the previous action sequence. For example, {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, assuming that effect is activated after executing {1, 1, 2}.

@netherEnd I misunderstood that the cycle was supposed to repeat. I have updated my answer, and I now I agree with your simulations.

Your answer is very perfect and clear, and I have to apologize for my earlier code bug.
